# Terraform trouble with list in a map using for_each

Tags: amazon-web-services, foreach, terraform

I'm trying to take each value from the list in the map and iterate over it with the description in a map for a prefix list but can't work out how.

Variable:

```
users = {
  "user1" = {
    description = ""
    secret_key_value = {
      username       = "user1"
      home_directory = "/user1/"
    }
    allowlist = ["200.0.0.1/32"]
  },
  "user2" = {
    description = ""
    secret_key_value = {
      username       = "user2"
      home_directory = "/user2/"
    }
    allowlist = ["200.0.0.5/32", "200.0.0.10/32"]
  }
```

Resource:

```
resource "aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list" "sftp" {
  count = local.prefix_list_enabled ? 1 : 0

  name           = "User Whitelist"
  address_family = "IPv4"
  max_entries    = 10

  dynamic "entry" {
    for_each = { 
      for k, v in var.users : k => v 
      if v.allowlist != "" || v.description != ""
    }

    content {
      cidr        = entry.value.allowlist
      description = entry.value.description
    }
  }
}
```

With the above, I'm getting "Inappropriate value for attribute "cidr": string required.". I need to break up the list values in the allowlist variable key and iterate through them with the description. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **flatten** your `users`:

```
locals {
  users_flat = merge([
    for k,v in var.users: {
      for cidr in v.allowlist:
        "${k}-${cidr}" => {
            description = v.description
            secret_key_value = v.secret_key_value
            "cidr"  = cidr
        }
      }
  ]...)   
}
```

then

```
  dynamic "entry" {
    for_each = local.users_flat

    content {
      cidr        = entry.value.cidr
      description = entry.value.description
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Marcin! This is useful, however the conditional if v.allowlist != "" is no longer possible?

Comment: @Lloyd No, because `allowlist` can't be an empty "string". I must be empty list.

Comment: Makes sense now. Kudos to you Marcin!